# How to get more tan 50 replies to a Vimeo api calls

Tags: vimeo-api

Below code is a modified version I found on stackoverflow 
My problem is that I dont know who to get more than 50 outputs using the page argument.
Moreover, I would like to get output in xml instead as of php

```
    <?php

    // Include the Vimeo API file. Download from here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib
    require_once('vimeo.php');

    /*
     * Helper Function to Handle Vimeo Authentication
     */
        function authenticate_vimeo(){
            // Settings below.
            // You'll need to set these to your account's as show here: // Get from https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new

            $vimeo_id = 'user2589275'; // Get from https://vimeo.com/settings, must be in the form of user123456
            $consumer_key = '5ae2e1e3f51248xx9dfbb19a05d6984d652195388';
            $consumer_secret = 'c3c3ad645c14fxx5868e3c7dfe4ed54180205bfd';
            $token = '4a152fbcce79c9efb0xx29a371ec0b82b';
            $token_secret = 'cadb71f5bf9b5bbxxx0967fe45afbe10d329624a';

            // Do an authentication call
            $vimeo = new phpVimeo($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
            $vimeo->setToken($token, $token_secret);
            $vimeo->user_id = $vimeo_id;

            return $vimeo;
        }

    /*
     * This is how you make a call to the Vimeo API
     */
        // Authenticate Vimeo
        $vimeo = authenticate_vimeo();

        // Try to access the API
        try {
            $args = array(
                'full_response' => true,
                'user_id'       => $vimeo->user_id, // This limits the request to the one user's videos
                'per_page'      => 50, // 50 is the max per page, use "page" parameter for more pages

            );
            $results = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getAll', $args); // List of methods here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods
        }
        catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
            $error = "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
        }

        //
        if( isset($error) ) {
            print_r($error);
        } else {
            $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");


            print_r($results); // This will be a gigantic PHP object of all videos and meta data
            fwrite($myfile, var_export($results, true));
            fclose($myfile);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not request more than 50 items on a single page. If you need to retrieve additional pages, add the `page` parameter.

First page

```
$args = array(
    'full_response' => true,
    'user_id'       => $vimeo->user_id, // This limits the request to the one user's videos
    'page'          => 1, // Request the first page
    'per_page'      => 50, // 50 is the max per page, use "page" parameter for more pages
);
```

Second Page

```
$args = array(
    'full_response' => true,
    'user_id'       => $vimeo->user_id, // This limits the request to the one user's videos
    'page'          => 2, // Request the second page
    'per_page'      => 50, // 50 is the max per page, use "page" parameter for more pages
);
```

etc. You can calculate the total amount of pages from two fields in the response body. Divide the total field by the perpage field